# Email Vaildation Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2

```
 jQuery(function() {
        var emailAddress = jQuery('#email_address');
        emailAddress.on("change", function () {
           var mail=emailAddress.val();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/customer/email/",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {email: mail},
                success: function (exist) {
                    if (exist == 1) {
                       alert("exist");
                    } else if (exist == 0) {
                        alert("exist");
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        alert("Error " + jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText);


                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Controller email.php

```
 public function execute()
{
    $customerEmail=$this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
    $objectManager=\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
    $CustomerModel->setWebsiteId(1);

    $CustomerModel->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
    $userId = $CustomerModel->getId();
    if ($userId) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

I want to check email before clicking create an account button using Ajax, i am not getting to do that, please help me out to solve this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to validate email address as customer enter his email address. For this you just need minor change in the email address field.

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email_address" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true, 'remote':'<?php echo $this->getUrl('customcustomer/index/uniqueemail', ['_secure' => true]); ?>'}"/>
```

Create a controller and add you logic in execute method.

```
<?php 
namespace Gaurav\CustomCustomer\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Uniqueemail extends Action
{
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
 */
 protected $resultJsonFactory;

 /**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer 
 */
 protected $_customerModel;

 /**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
 */
 public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
     \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerModel
 ) {
     $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
     $this->_customerModel = $customerModel;
     parent::__construct($context);
 }

 public function execute()
 {
     $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
     $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
     $customerData = $this->_customerModel->getCollection()
                   ->addFieldToFilter('email', $email);
     if(!count($customerData)) {
       $resultJson->setData('true');
     } else {
       $resultJson->setData('That email is already taken, try another one');
     }
     return $resultJson;
 }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful to you.